# how to show a modal outside a flutter app

Tags: android, flutter

Is there any way to show modal outside a flutter application without launching the app, like Microsoft To Do or Pocket in android.

[image: Pocket Popup]

[image: Microsoft To Do]

Answer (score 0):

Use the dialog widget.  You then wrap a stateless or stateful widget with it.  Use the async feature to suspend control making the dialog modeless

```
  Future<bool> _onMyDialog() async {
      return await showDialog<bool>(
          context: context,
           builder: (context) {
             return Dialog(child: YourCustomStatelessWidget());
         });
   }
```

YourCustomStatelessWidget

```
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
 return Dialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      ),
      elevation: 0.0,
      child: Scrollbar(
          isAlwaysShown: true,
          controller: _scrollController,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
              controller: _scrollController,
              child: Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: WidgetList)))));
}
```

Comment: the dialog widget should have a context from the app, what i need is floated dialog or popup when the app closed